# How to put the application user username on the picture as a result to post on wall?

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

What i want to do is to share a picture. However, i hope to put the facebook username on my picture to share on wall.How can i get the username and put it inside the picture? Anyone can help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this great article - http://blog.doh.ms/2008/02/12/adding-text-to-images-in-real-time-with-php/

Or google for `PHP GD` or `PHP ImageMagick`